# Recordeditform - Checkbox Issues

Tags: aura, lightning-recordeditform, checkbox

I've an Aura component where recordeditform is used to create contact record.  I added a checkbox field to the recordeditform but it doesn't save to created records.

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="formcnt"
          objectApiName="Contact"
          class="slds-card__body_inner">

<lightning:messages/>


<div >
    <lightning:inputField variant="label-inline" onchange="{!c.onValueChange}" name="fname" fieldName="FirstName" required="true" value="{!v.ppt.FirstName}" />
</div> 
<div >
    <lightning:inputField variant="label-inline" onchange="{!c.onValueChange}" name="chck" fieldName="Checkbox__c" required="true" value="{!v.ppt.Checkbox__c}" />
</div>

</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Above is the code snippet. When creating a record, all fields are populated correctly but just the checkbox field always says false even when its checked.

Please let me know.

Comment: Can you share what are you doing in `onValueChange` as I can see everything works fine and I am able to successfully create a record with checkbox value as true.

Comment: There is nothing on "onValueChange ". Just using toggles to hide/show few things. No data binding happening there

Comment: In that case, I dont see why it should fail. I tried the same and it works fine. Please find my component below.

Answer (score 0):

cmp file.

```
<aura:component description="editForm" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride,lightning:isUrlAddressable">
    <aura:attribute access="global" name="ppt" type="Contact"></aura:attribute>
    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="formcnt"
                              objectApiName="Contact"
                              class="slds-card" onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}">

        <lightning:messages/>


        <div >
            <lightning:inputField variant="label-inline" onchange="{!c.onValueChange}" name="fname" fieldName="FirstName" required="true" value="{!v.ppt.FirstName}" />
            <lightning:inputField variant="label-inline" onchange="{!c.onValueChange}" name="lname" fieldName="LastName" required="true" value="{!v.ppt.LastName}" />
        </div>
        <div >
            <lightning:inputField variant="label-inline" onchange="{!c.onValueChange}" name="chck" fieldName="Checkbox__c" required="true" value="{!v.ppt.Checkbox__c}" />
        </div>

        <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create contact" />
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:component>
```

And I have commented `onValueChange` as you mentioned you dont have anything there.

```
({
    onValueChange: function (component, event, helper) {
        //console.log( event.getSource().get("v.fieldName"));
        //console.log( event.getSource().getAttribute('checked'));
    },

    handleSubmit: function (component, event, helper){
        event.preventDefault();
        const fields = event.getParam('fields');
        component.find('formcnt').submit(fields);
    }
});
```

Then I can see `checkbox__c` value getting properly passed and marked as checked.

[image]

**NOTE : Not a production ready code. Modify attributes as required.**

Answer (score 0):

Don't use value in the checkbox

```
<lightning:inputField variant="label-inline" onchange="{!c.onValueChange}" name="chck" fieldName="Checkbox__c" required="true" value="{!v.ppt.Checkbox__c}" />
```

instead use checked

```
<lightning:input type="checkbox" aura:id="chck" required="true" checked="{!v.ppt.Checkbox__c}" />
```

Then you don't need an onchange funtion
I did it with plain lightning:input and it works fine for me